# Azure Active Directory - supporting multi-tenant consented app scenario

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Scenario: I'm developing a multi-tenant consented application leveraging Azure Active Directory. The application can be thought of as a closed loop star network. I would like to do the following:
1. Whitelist tenants that can "see" my app at design time.
2. Enable cert based authentication - In a single tenant this would be straight-forward. However, I'm a little confused what it means in the multi-tenant scenario. Each app( i.e., organization) brings its own certificate. In a S2S scenario, the nodes in the client organization's tenant nodes would have these certs installed and the keyCredential for the client organization's AAD application would have the public key token configured. How then does this claim get validated on the target "Resource" application that resides in an entirely different tenant.? 
3. I expose a oAuth2Permissions in my application and would like to automate the scenario using PowerShell. I have sample code that does somethign alone the lines of:

```
$serviceApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName <AADApplicationName> -AvailableToOtherTenants $true -IdentifierUris $serviceAppIdUri `


$aad_oAuth2Perm_ReadModel = 
[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.OAuth2Permission]::New()
$aad_oAuth2Perm_ReadModel.AdminConsentDescription = ($adminConsentDisplay -f  "Model")
$aad_oAuth2Perm_ReadModel.AdminConsentDisplayName = ($adminConsentDisplay -f  "Model")
$aad_oAuth2Perm_ReadModel.Id = [guid]::NewGuid().Guid.ToString()
$aad_oAuth2Perm_ReadModel.IsEnabled = $true
$aad_oAuth2Perm_ReadModel.Type = 'User'
$aad_oAuth2Perm_ReadModel.UserConsentDescription = ($userConsentDisplay -f  "Model")
$aad_oAuth2Perm_ReadModel.UserConsentDisplayName = ($userConsentDisplay -f  "Model")
$aad_oAuth2Perm_ReadModel.Value = "Read.Model"
$aad_oAuth2Permissions.Add($aad_oAuth2Perm_ReadModel) 

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $serviceApplication.ObjectId.Guid.ToString() `                    
-Oauth2Permissions $aad_oAuth2Permissions
```

---

The Set-AzureADApplication call always fails with this error below

*Set-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing SetApplication 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Property  value cannot be deleted unless it is disabled first.*

I believe I might have to delete the default "user_impersonation" oAuth2Permission that is created with the New-AzureRmADApplication call but none of what I've tried works. How do I go about deleting specific oAuth2Permissions or replace them with Set-AzureADApplication ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that new applications come with a default OAuth 2 Permission, and you are trying to `SET` a brand new permission without including the old default permission, which is the same as a `DELETE` operation.

One solution would be to read all the existing OAuth 2 Permissions on the application, and then add your new permission along side the existing ones, and then do the `SET` call.  This will then avoid the "delete" call that is going on.

The other option is to do as the API is warning you. There is an existing OAuth 2 Permission, which needs to be `IsEnabled=$false` before it can be deleted. You can, before trying to add a new permission, read in the old permission, disable the permission, then delete it.

I believe either of this solutions will work to resolve your specific error message. To be completely clear, I did not really understand your scenario, so I do not know if even after you solve this problem, you will accomplish your ultimate goal.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Shawn, your suggestion to read in existing permissions and disable them along with the new permission set worked. That answers #3 in my original list of questions. With questions #1 & #2 I'm trying to essentially A) Find a way to scope a multi-tenant app to a restricted set of tenants either at design time by way of whitelisting or at runtime by being able to validate a set of relevant claims B) Trying to find how certificate based authorization can be implemented in this scenario.

Comment: Multi-Tenant applications in Azure Active Directory have no inherit limitations to which tenants can use the application. AAD also does not support any customization like this in the configuration. Instead, you must configure this yourself through your service by using the Graph API or content in the token to determine whether or not the tenant meets your criteria.

Comment: Ok. appRoles and oAuthorizationPermissions are client bound claims - as in anyone can accept those and present the relevant claims in the token. What as a resource application can I demand of the client resource? My question is can I have the client present keyCredentials for e.g., This again would be odd, since the client must somehow have my certificate with him to be able to generate those claims in the token.

Comment: As a resource, you can control some of the "additional claims" which appear in the token such as Group Membership Claims, Directory Role Claims, Security Group Claims. However anything related to the client certificate or things of that nature are only to be shared between the client and the identity provider. You as a resource should be opaque to the secret used during authentication.

Comment: Are these claim types applicable in a multi-tenant scenario?

Comment: Yes, of course. I would suggest you open another question thread to discuss your other topics. When you create a single post which asks 3 questions, you will not get a good answer to any of them. Come up with concrete, scenario driven examples, of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for all the suggestions. I cannot upvote but you've effectively addressed most of my questions.